# Multivariant classification imbalance dataset

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes

The dataset head looks like this. ( working in RStudio)
head(df)

```
  air_purifier_page_top checkout_page_top contactus_top
1                     0                 0             0
2                     0                 0             0
3                     0                 0             0
6                     0                 0             0
7                    20                 0             0
9                     0                 0             0
  customer_service_amc_login_top customer_service_request_login_top
1                              0                                  0
2                              0                                  0
3                              0                                  0
6                              0                                  0
7                              0                                 51
9                              0                                  0
  demo_page_top offer_page_top security_solutions_page_top sessionDuration
1             0              0                           0              91
2             7              0                           0               7
3             0              0                           0             141
6             9              0                           0               9
7            43              0                           0             806
9            10              0                           0              10
  sessionDuration_hist storelocator_top successbookdemo_top
1                 1069                0                   0
2                    0                0                   0
3                  248                0                   0
6                    0                0                   0
7                    0                0                   0
9                    0                0                   0
  vacuum_cleaner_page_top water_purifier_page_top converted_in_7days
1                      91                       0                  0
2                       0                       0                  0
3                       0                     142                  0
6                       0                       0                  0
7                       0                     227                  0
9                       0                       0                  0
```

target is "converted_in_7days", it has 4 class ( ie 0,1,2,3 ) and dataset is imbalanced.
Can someone suggest any package and function (in R-Studio) which deals multiclass imbalanced data problem ?
Thanks in advance.
PS: ROSE works in binary only.

Comment: I have a question (currently with an open bounty) on how to diagnose that a class imbalance problem exists here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539638/how-do-you-know-that-your-classifier-is-suffering-from-class-imbalance?noredirect=1#comment992080_539638 .  Are you sure you have an imbalance problem and that the classifier isn't just giving the correct answer to the question as posed?

Comment: Why do you see the imbalance as something in need of correction? Standard models like multinomial logistic regression handle the imbalance without an issue.