# Proving a class imbalance IS a problem in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, unbalanced-classes

Context: Have been trying to create a prediction model for a 1% outcome variable using Random Forest Machine Learning for a large health survey (entirely multi-level categorical data, yes/no outcome, ~230,000 observations initially). Stupidly high amount of missing values, poor data collection and the need to infer between variable. Multiple imputation used, CCA used (as a separate base), k-fold CV, train/test split, the lot. Whilst under-sampling improved things marginally, over-sampling was pretty much consistent with no sampling at all (~140,000 observations now, with perfect sensitivity and no specificity reached - i.e., unhelpful). Whilst Random forest can handle this type of data well, I understand it has its limitations (especially with class imbalance and biasness towards certain predictors).

ANYWAY:

I've read a bit of ML research, and I don't claim to understand all of it, but there's sometimes a pretty solid paper on improper methods for ML. Presently, I understand multiple logistic regression SHOULD be able to handle the class imbalance - but in my case, I still get nearly perfective sensitivity and 0 specificity.

Does this then justify the use of a balancing method in that the imbalance is now a problem, or am I missing something? Have just been using the Caret train package for most training needs.

Comment: perfect sensitivity and zero specificity (assigning all patterns to the majority class) may well be the optimal solution for the learning task as posed, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539638/how-do-you-know-that-your-classifier-is-suffering-from-class-imbalance .  If this is not acceptable, it means that false negatives are worse errors than false positives, and the solution is cost-sensitive learning (and the level of imbalance is irrelevant to the implementation of that).

Comment: When you write about sensitivity and specificity, you are obviously thinking in terms of "hard" classifications, which unfortunately most "ML" methods output by default. Logistic regressions give you *probabilistic* classifications, which I would argue are much more suitable. To go from probabilistic to hard classifications, you need a threshold, and the trivial hardcoded one of 0.5 is usually not useful at all, especially for "unbalanced" data. [See here for more information.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't.  Think of it this way - I don't even need a model, or any predictors, to get a $99\%$ sensitivity.  That's great!  I can do this because the prior odds are $99-1$ in favor of one of the classes; call it $A$.  To predict the other class ($B$), you'd need your data+model to be strong enough to indicate $> 99-1$ odds in favor of $B$.  That's pretty strong. And if you don't have a collection of features that, together,  give you those odds or better, then the odds are that $A$ is the correct class.  Pretending otherwise (by, for example, oversampling) will likely hurt you when it comes to generalizing to out-of-sample data.

One situation in which this isn't the case is if the losses of misclassification are asymmetric.  If misclassifying a $B$ is $10\times$ as expensive as misclassifying an $A$, you'd be better off predicting a $B$ if the odds are better than $10-1$ against.  However, you don't need oversampling to do this - you can look at the probabilities, and, instead of using the default $> 50\%$ rule for classifying, use, say, a $> 10\%$ rule.